# Excel Formula Help INDEX MATCH Dates

Tags: excel, indexing, match, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I have been working on this formula for the last 40 minutes and I can't really figure out where I'm doing wrong. I would really appreciate the community's help.

I have provided a screen shot below.

For some reason the formula is only taking the first instance of the currency provided in "column O:O" and it is not adding up the multiple instances of the matching months and year. I tried putting SUM in the formula but I got an error.

[image: I INDEX MATCH the MONTH and YEAR but it is not adding all the instances of the matching MONTH and YEAR]

Comment: Though I did answer you below, please, next time put the formula you have tried in the post as text and not just a photo.

Comment: Hi Mr. Scott, thank you very much for your explanation. I will make sure to put the actual formula in the body of my question like you have suggested.

Comment: Have a safe and awesome New Years celebration!

Comment: did my answer work for you?  If so please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Mr. Scott, this worked like a charm but may I ask you why you chose to use this type of formula "MONTH(D17)=MONTH($M$2:$M$6))*(YEAR(D17)=YEAR($M$2:$M$6))" for the MONTH and YEAR instead of what I had used "MONTH(D17)&YEAR(D17),MONTH(M:M)&YEAR(M:M),0" also what dose the multiple sign * do in this formula? Thank you very much for your help and explanation.

Comment: the `*` works like an `AND`.  The Boolean values return 1 or 0 so it will return 1 if both are TRUE.  One could have done: `--(MONTH($M$2:$M$6) & YEAR($M$2:$M$6) = MONTH(D17) & YEAR(D17))` in its place but you will turn numbers to text and then back to numbers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131833/discussion-between-christopher-khanbabaian-and-scott-craner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INDEX/MATCH And VLOOKUP will only return the first instance.

You will need to use SUMPRODUCT() to return what you want:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(D17)=MONTH($M$2:$M$6))*(YEAR(D17)=YEAR($M$2:$M$6)),$O$2:$O$6)
```

Note:  SUMPRODUCT is an Array Type formula an thus the cell references should include only those that have data and avoid full column data.

[image]